# Is the memory allocated for different data types will depend on the architecture?

Tags: c

Hi all is the memory allocated for different types of variable say float, int and char is different for different architecture?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, definitely.  `int`, in particular, is particularly prone to that: old 8-bit and 16-bit architectures invariably had 16-bit `int`s, while today's 32-bit and 64-bit ones invariably use 32-bit `int`s.  That's how `int` is defined to *be* -- the "natural" size of integers for the architecture you're compiling for!

Comment: @Alex `int` can be a non-native word size.  gcc for OS X these days is like that - 64-bit programs, but `int` is 32-bits.

Comment: @Carl, of course -- I did mention that 64-bit architectures' C compilers "invariably" (a bit of an overbid;-) use 32-bit ints -- they get away with it because, also "invariably" (;-), 64-bit architectures impose no speed penalty for dealing w/32-bit ints (not true for 32-bit architectures and 16-bit ints, in many cases).

Comment: yup.  I just wanted to clarify about the "natural" size not necessarily being `int`.

Answer (score 5):

It's definitely the case that `float`, `int`, and `char` may be of different sizes on different devices, yes.  It's implementation-defined by your C compiler.  All you can count on for really portable code is that:

```
sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)
```

And that `sizeof(char) == 1`.  There are a bunch of types in C99 that are of specific bit sizes, those may be useful to you if you need to keep type size portable from architecture to architecture.

Edit:  I looked up the information in the spec.  Section 5.2.4.2.1, "Sizes of integer types", is what you're looking for:

> ...implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown...
>
> ```
> UCHAR_MAX         255 // 2^8 - 1
> USHRT_MAX       65535 // 2^16 - 1
> UINT_MAX        65535 // 2^16 - 1
> ULONG_MAX  4294967295 // 2^32 − 1
> ```

And so on...

Comment: So the code written in the 64 bit architecture may not work in 16 bit or 32 bit architecture right?

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it's a complete YES. However, there's also the part about endianness which nobody has mentioned. Different architectures can store the bytes that make up a type in different orders as well.